# Akka Actor Selection

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am maintaining an actor registry as follows:

```
val system = ActorSystem("MySystem")
val actorRegistry = HashMap[String, ActorRef]()

def process(msg: Message, keys: List[String]): Unit = {
  for (key <- keys) {

    //Lookup the actor or create a new actor and register
    val actor = actorRegistry getOrElseUpdate(key, 
      system actorOf(Props[MyActor], name = key))

    actor ! msg
  }
}
```

Is this an idiomatic approach, or should I be implementing this with `ActorSelection`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to consider using [Akka Routing](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html). An example from the doc:

```
import akka.routing.ActorRefRoutee
import akka.routing.Router
import akka.routing.RoundRobinRoutingLogic

class Master extends Actor {
    var router = {
        val routees = Vector.fill(5) {
            val r = context.actorOf(Props[Worker])
            context watch r
            ActorRefRoutee(r)
        }
        Router(RoundRobinRoutingLogic(), routees)
    }

    def receive = {
        case w: Work =>
            router.route(w, sender())
        case Terminated(a) =>
            router = router.removeRoutee(a)
            val r = context.actorOf(Props[Worker])
            context watch r
            router = router.addRoutee(r)
    }
}
```

You code looks quite similar to a regular router, i.e. you have a bunch of actors of the same type `MyActor` processing the same type of messages `Message`. If you use `akka.routing.BroadcastRoutingLogic` to send the message to all routees you would achieve something very similar to what you have and you will have all the support of the framework for dealing with failures. The minor difference is that your list of `keys` might potentially be smaller than `actorRegistry` but even that could be implemented with custom `RoutingLogic` if really needed.

Comment: It wasn't clear from my sample code, but in fact `keys` will usually be a small subset of the `actorRegistry`.  Looks like a custom router is an option for me though.

Comment: `ActorSelection` might be more idiomatic if you can use a wildcard or path segment to select subset of actors that you need. ActorSelection behaves differently in terms of actor lifecycle. Finally, your code looks good as it is. :)